# java keystore CA certificate validity extension

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keystore, websphere-liberty

I had a CA certificate which is expiring this year. My key.jks file list as below.

```
inter, Dec 17, 2019, trustedCertEntry,
....
root, Dec 17, 2019, trustedCertEntry,
....
app.domain.com, Dec 29, 2019, PrivateKeyEntry,
```

To extend validity I gave the same CSR file given last year. Now I have new 3 crt files for inter, root and domain-name.

Now I tried to remove old entries by

```
keytool -delete -alias inter -keystore key.jks -storepass pword
keytool -delete -alias root -keystore key.jks -storepass pword
keytool -delete -alias app.domain.com -keystore key.jks -storepass pword
```

and imported the new cert files like

```
keytool -import -alias inter -file intermediate.crt -keystore key.jks -storepass pword
keytool -import -alias root -file TrustedRoot.crt -keystore key.jks -storepass pword
keytool -import -alias app.domain.com -file app_domain_com.crt -keystore key.jks -storepass pword
```

Now `keytool -list` does not show PrivateKeyEntry for app_domain_com.crt and application not coming up.

```
inter, Dec 15, 2020, trustedCertEntry,
....
root, Dec 15, 2020, trustedCertEntry,
....
app.doamin.com, Dec 15, 2020, trustedCertEntry,
```

I have ADFS SSO integration and wanted to avoid changes with it because of this certificate change.

Comment: If you got a new certificate from the _same CA_ as before, there's a good chance it uses the same root and intermediate(s) -- those are usually much longer-lived than end-entity certs which typically are a year or less. If you checked beforehand and found they were the same, you could avoid deleting and reinserting them. That said, your real problem was deleting the privatekeyentry for the end-entity, as rookie correctly answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third delete command deleted your private key as well. That's why your application is broken, you need your private key for SSL to work.

When you said you wanted to reuse the same CSR that was used last time, it means you were planning on using the same private key, but you deleted it. That's why you see them as different types after you deleted and imported. In your first keytool `list` you have app.domain.com as a PrivateKeyEntry (contains private key and certificate), but after you deleted and imported the cert, you have the app.domain.com as a TrustedCertEntry (only certificate). If you had not deleted the private key, the import command will have associated the new certificate with it, since the private key is not found, it just adds the certificate.

In your case you should have done these steps:

1. Not run the third delete command
2. Imported the new certificate and associated with the existing private key using keytool's `-importcert` command.

Something to consider when trying to reuse the same CSR as last time can be found [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131188/do-i-need-a-new-csr-for-a-certificate-renewal/131192), [here](https://www.geocerts.com/support/do-i-need-a-new-csr-to-renew-my-ssl-certificate) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/286102/can-i-reuse-a-ssl-csr).

P.S: I hope you have backed up your original keystore.